# How to get a result from a single array PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How do I view a result from this array. For example if a user login with there Email address example1@example.com it should only show their info.

I have bean looking for an answer online with no luck. I find that my Array results dose not show a ID 1,2,3, may that be the reason for it not to work? can I create a ID with PHP or table? Or is it a simple code that I am missing. I have followed all the steps from www.w3schools.com for tables and PHP, and I still know I am missing something. I just don't see what it is yet. I am aware there may be a answer to this already, but I am having trouble finding it on Google for a answer as I don't know what to look for in the searches. Is there anything I can do?

As well, if you can direct me somewhere usefull for me to learn more that will be good as well.

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [EmailAddr] => example1@example.com
    [Password] => 123456
    [client] => 555555
    [firstname] => first
    [lastname] => name
)

Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [EmailAddr] => example2@example.com
    [Password] => 987654
    [client] => 555556
    [firstname] => my
    [lastname] => name
)
```

Here is the code.

```
$sql = "SELECT id, EmailAddr, Password, client, firstname, lastname FROM table";
$result = $conn->query($sql);



if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


      //  echo "id: " . $row["EmailAddr"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br><br><br>";
    ?><pre><?print_r($row); ?></pre><?
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: `... FROM table WHERE EmailAddr = 'example1@gmail.com'`

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text!**. Only store password hashes! Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: @AbraCadaver when i used  $sql = "SELECT id, FROM table WHERE EmailAddr = '$email'"; i received 0 results.

Comment: ...then you're searching for a non-existing email. Make sure it isn't misspelled or have any spaces before or after (in both the search string and in the database).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Good idea just one quchtion if i do use your meshed, will the user be able to view there password? and  change it? As well will i be able to view it. As i really want the user to create 2 types of passwords. one that the user creates a private one for site login and 2 for myself so i can set up the password he created for a device setup.

Comment: Then what is in `$email` is not in the table in `EmailAddr`.  Also, use a prepared statement: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: There's no reason to show the passwords for _anyone_ (including the user), _ever_. Passwords are secret. Only the user should know it. There should be no way for you or anyone else to be able to see it. If they want to change the password, you just overwrite the password hash with a new hash in the database. I you want to use the same password for the user somewhere else, you could just copy the hash.

Comment: ...remember, if you are able to find out the users password, anyone that gains access to your server/database can also find it out. _Never_ assume that your application is 100% safe for attacks.

Comment: @AbraCadaver i tried the email address is defiantly in the table.   $sql = "SELECT EmailAddr, FROM table WHERE EmailAddr = 'myemail@gmail.com'"; dose this code look correct to you? fyi i tried different ways. but still nothing.

Comment: @AbraCadaver SELECT  EmailAddr = 'myemail@gmail.com' FROM mytable worked for me. if you mark your answer i will mark it accepted. edited wow new issue is that only the email is selected from the array. how do i get the entire array from this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```sql
SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE  EmailAddr='myemail@gmail.com';
```

where `id` is the value you want to pull out from the table. See https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp for more info.